# Transpose CSV using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv which as data for around 1500 locations and is in the below format:

```
LOCATION 10/23/2018 10/24/2018 10/25/2018 10/26/2018
0001       350         351        500         600
0002       400         200         400         250
0005        250        200         300         400
```

and the list of location goes on an on for around 1500 locations.

The desired output that i need is :

```
LOCATION    DATE         VALUE
0001      10/23/2018      350
0001      10/24/2018      351
0001      10/25/2018      500
```

As can be seen from the above output , i need the python program to create two new fields ( DATE and VALUE) in addition to do transpose the fields. I literally dont know how to create it as a python as i have not worked on python much.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html). Assuming you've read the data into a DataFrame named `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.melt(df, 
        id_vars='LOCATION', 
        var_name='DATE',
        value_name='VALUE')
```

#### Output:

```
   LOCATION        DATE VALUE
0      0001  10/23/2018   350
1      0002  10/23/2018   400
2      0005  10/23/2018   250
3      0001  10/24/2018   351
4      0002  10/24/2018   200
5      0005  10/24/2018   200
6      0001  10/25/2018   500
7      0002  10/25/2018   400
8      0005  10/25/2018   300
9      0001  10/26/2018   600
10     0002  10/26/2018   250
11     0005  10/26/2018   400
```

Comment: In my opinion `value_vars=[c for c in df.columns if c != 'LOCATION'],` is not necessary ;)